# What font is used by Microsoft in the Visual Studio Feedback form?

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-2015

Can someone please help identify the font that is used in the Visual Studio 2015's feedback screen(see screenshot)?[image]

Comment: Font doesn't matter, what matter is what coding you have done !! Even though you use awesome fonts ,your code can be ugly as hell !

Comment: Pratik every bit in an application makes for user experience. If the application developers has made an effort on providing a solid user experience the user is more likely to interact with and use the applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Segoe UI**. Found it using Live Visual Tree.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but that doesn't look like the same font. Can you share more details about Live Visual Tree tool so I can verify myself? Thanks.

Comment: Debug - Attach to process devenv.exe from a second VS instance. Debug - Windows - Live Visual Tree.

Comment: I'd be damned! You are right although when I put the same font in my Windows Form control the look is completely different. Nevermind though, thanks a lot